# Trying to write script to convert gmail emails from a specific sender into a PDF

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm trying to write a Google Apps Script that will retrieve all gmail mail from a specific sender, convert it into a PDF, and save it in a folder on Drive.  I can't figure out how to specifically pull from a certain sender.

This is some code that I pulled from someone and tried to modify but it's throwing an error.  I'm very much a coding noob.

```
function saveGmail() {
  GmailUtils.eachMessage('from:email@email.com', 100, function(message) {
    // create a pdf of the message
    var pdf = GmailUtils.messageToPdf(message);

    // prefix the pdf filename with a date string
    pdf.setName(GmailUtils.formatDate(message, 'yyyyMMdd - ') + pdf.getName());

    // save the converted file to the 'Expenses' folder within Google Drive
    DriveUtils.getFolder('Gmail To PDF').createFile(pdf);

    // signal that we are done with this email and it will be marked as read
    return true;
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you installed the two extensions GmailUtils and DriveUtils?  Also what is the error?

Comment: Yes.  I've added both libraries to the script.  I actually fixed the error but what's happening is it's pulling all emails that has included that person's email as a sender or receiver.  I'd like it to pull only emails that have been sent from the emailer in the code to the receiver running a script.  (We need to log every email that was sent from a specific person to another person)...that's the ultimate goal.